# What is the best way to share variables with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, global-variables, share

I have these variables that I want to share it with another screen, what is the best way to share them beside Pushing them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try working with Singletons, store your variables in a singleton class and share them across screens.

```dart
class YourClass {
  static YourClass _instance;

  YourClass._();

  static YourClass get instance => _instance = _instance ?? YourClass._();

  // Your instance variables that you want to share can go here
  var isVisible = false

}
```

Comment: ok but how to get its value in another screen ? Just import and use ?

Comment: Yes, you simply do YourClass.instance.isVisible ... you can create additional getters and setters or any logic in that class that helps simplify your task. Though I would like to point out that this is not the best way to share variables, I personally use rxDart with Stream Providers